# The eclipse icon on my KDE desktop looks wrong

Tags: kde, eclipse, kde4

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Here is how it is configured:

[image]

I want the icon to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If installed from software center, the icon is located here `/usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.png`

It looks like your icon description links to the binary not the icon file(it should probably end in xpm or png).

Tested on 12.04 LTS